# como listar os repositórios do github dentro de uma conta que tenha determinado topico

Tags: javascript, github

Meu problema é o seguinte to consumindo a api do github via fetch do javascript, e quero buscar dentro dos meus repositórios, os que tenham um determinado tópico como "Javacript" ou "Programação" o problema é que não achei um jeito de fazer isso usando a api do git.

Até agora só tenho isso.

```
  async function start()
    {
        const api = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/LucasFernandoWeb/repos');
            const data = await response.json();

            return data;
        }

        const api_data = await api();

        console.log(api_data);

    }

    // Carrega os cards
    start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a [API de search](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories), utilizando o parâmetro `q` para formular *queries* mais avançadas.

Por exemplo, o seguinte *endpoint* irá retornar todos os repositórios na linguagem TypeScript para o usuário lffg:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user%3Alffg%20language%3ATypeScript
```

Você pode usar a [ferramenta de busca](https://github.com/search/advanced) do GitHub para gerar queries que você pode usar no parâmetro `q`. A [documentação](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-based-on-the-contents-of-a-repository) também te dá mais detalhes sobre cada opção.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda